# Incorrect syntax found during sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server

The following script I have tried to run in MS server management studio and this is work perfectly fine.

```
SELECT ucb.UserFirstName, ucb.UserLastName, ucb.userid, c.caseid
FROM Cases c 
    LEFT JOIN Users ucb ON (c.ConfirmedBy=ucb.UserID) 
    JOIN RealtorStaff rs ON c.realtorstaffid=rs.realtorstaffid 
WHERE c.ConfirmedBy is not null AND c.CaseStatusID <> 7 
    AND (
            SELECT COUNT(ServiceID) 
            FROM Cases ca JOIN Services s ON ca.CaseID=s.CaseID 
            WHERE ca.CaseID=c.CaseID 
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 8 
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 9 
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 10 
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 14 
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 15 
                AND s.ServiceStatusID != 7)>0 
    AND c.DateConfirmed >= '2010-08-06 00:00:00' 
    AND c.DateConfirmed <= '2010-08-06 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY ucb.UserFirstName, ucb.UserLastName, c.caseid
```

Somehow after I tried to convert it into the following scrip so that I can run it under sp_executesql and error message display (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '8').

```
--  /* for testing purpose
    Declare @startdate DATETIME; set @startdate = '2010-08-06'
    Declare @enddate DATETIME; set @enddate = '2010-08-06'
--  */

    Declare @actualstartdate varchar(20); set @actualstartdate = replace(convert(char(26),@startdate,102),'.','-')+' 00:00:00'
    Declare @actualenddate varchar(20); set @actualenddate = replace(convert(char(26),@enddate,102),'.','-')+' 23:59:58'

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ucb.UserFirstName, ucb.UserLastName, ucb.userid, c.caseid
                 INTO ##actual_assigned_cases
                 FROM Cases c 
                    LEFT JOIN Users ucb ON (c.ConfirmedBy=ucb.UserID) 
                    JOIN RealtorStaff rs ON c.realtorstaffid=rs.realtorstaffid 
                 WHERE c.ConfirmedBy is not null '

    SET @SQL = @SQL+' AND c.CaseStatusID <> 7 
                AND (SELECT COUNT(ServiceID) 
                FROM Cases ca 
                    JOIN Services s ON ca.CaseID=s.CaseID 
                WHERE ca.CaseID=c.CaseID 
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 8
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 9
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 10 
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 14
                AND s.ServiceTypeID != 15 
                AND s.ServiceStatusID != 7) > 0'


    SET @SQL = @SQL+' AND c.DateConfirmed >= '''+@actualstartdate+''' 
                AND c.DateConfirmed <= '''+@actualenddate+'''
                ORDER BY ucb.UserFirstName, ucb.UserLastName, c.caseid'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? and how can I fix this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than 500 chars, so `@SQL` got truncated.
change to:

```
  DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
```

Comment: Nitpick - nvarchar caps out at 4000 ;-)

Comment: nvarchar(4000) or nvarchar(max)

Comment: you are the superman... by the way.. the max nvarchar is only 4000 :)

Answer (score 3):

do a `print @sql` AKA `the poor man's debugger` and the problem will be revealed, my guess is that nvarchar(500) is not enough..make it 2000

Also take a look at [Changing exec to sp_executesql doesn't provide any benefit if you are not using parameters correctly](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/changing-exec-to-sp_executesql-doesn-t-p) to see how to use parameter so that execution plans can be reused

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried printing @SQL to see what is inside the variable?

Taking what you have and printing it, I get this:

```
SELECT ucb.UserFirstName, ucb.UserLastName, ucb.userid, c.caseid
                 INTO ##actual_assigned_cases
                 FROM Cases c 
                    LEFT JOIN Users ucb ON (c.ConfirmedBy=ucb.UserID) 
                    JOIN RealtorStaff rs ON c.realtorstaffid=rs.realtorstaffid 
                 WHERE c.ConfirmedBy is not null  AND c.CaseStatusID <> 7 
                AND (SELECT COUNT(ServiceID) 
                FROM Cases ca 
                    JOIN Services s ON ca.CaseI
```

It looks like your @SQL variable isn't big enough -- try nvarchar(max).